# Which episodes of Star Trek TNG led to their writers becoming regular staff?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes, production

Most TV episodes, and it seems so for TNG too, are written by existing writing staff, or come from freelance screenplays whose writers rarely, if ever contribute to the show again. Occasionally an outsider submits a script that makes enough of an impression to lead to the writer being hired as regular writing staff.

Two examples are [The Bonding](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Bonding) which led to the beginning of [Ronald D. Moore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_D._Moore)'s career, and [The Measure Of A Man](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_(episode)), whose writer [Melinda M. Snodgrass](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Melinda_M._Snodgrass) became a writer and story editor for the show.

Which episodes are there?

Comment: This question came on the Close Vote review and was flagged as "off-topic". I am voting to Leave Open as this question is about an on-topic work, and questions about fandom and behind-the-scenes are on-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Michael Piller

*Episode 3x01, **[Evolution](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Evolution_(episode))***

Piller was called by one of the lead writers during Season 2 of TNG to write a few episodes; his first work, ***Evolution*** (the Opening of Season 3), and some subsequent episodes he wrote were appreciated so much that he eventually became one of the main writers and producers, not only in TNG but also in DS9 and VOY.
Some of the most appreciated episodes of the whole show, like ***Yesterday's Enterprise*** and especially ***The Best of both Worlds*** were written by him.

<sub>Reference: [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Piller)</sub>

---

### René Echevarria

*Episode 3x16, **[The Offspring](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Offspring_(episode))***

Echevarria sent the unsolicited script for ***The Offspring*** while working as a waiter. He then become a regular writer for both TNG and DS9. Some of his most notable works for TNG are ***I, Borg***, ***True Q***, ***Face of the Enemy***, ***Second Chances*** and ***Lower Decks***.

<sub>Reference: [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Echevarria)</sub>

---

### Brannon Braga, Joe Menosky, Naren Shankar

These three writers joined TNG as interns during Season 4, and mostly had roles of story editors. Thus, they don't strictly have a single "first episode" that made the producers aware of their talents, but all of them afterwards had major writing and producing roles on TNG and subsequent series.

Some notable episodes:

- Braga: ***Cause and Effect***, ***Timescape***, ***Parallels***, ***All Good Things...***
- Menosky: ***Darmok***, ***The Chase***
- Shankar: ***The First Duty***, ***The Quality of Life***, ***Gambit***

<sub>Reference: Memory Alpha - [Braga](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Brannon_Braga) - [Menosky](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Joe_Menosky) - [Shankar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Naren_Shankar)</sub>